# Check response header's value in Postman tests

Tags: testing, automated-tests, postman

I would like to check the value from a concrete response header ("Location") as Test Results in Postman.
In the Postman's documentation I found examples of how to check the existance of headers with

```
pm.test("Content-Type is present", function () {
   pm.response.to.have.header("Content-Type");
});
```

But what I'm looking for is something like

```
pm.test("Location value is correct", function () {
   CODE HERE THAT CHECKS "Location" HEADER EQUALS TO SOMETHING;
});
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
pm.test("Redirect location is correct", function () {
   pm.response.to.have.header("Location");
   pm.response.to.be.header("Location", "http://example.com/expected-redirect-url");
});
```

Comment: Sandbox you very much!

Comment: you're sandbox! :)

Comment: With Postman v7.35.0, remember to turn off _Automatically follow redirects_ in Settings to see the Redirect response.

Comment: You could also use just the line
`pm.response.to.have.header("Location", "http://example.com/expected-redirect-url");`

Answer (score 21):

Here is another way of fetching the specific response header in Tests section ...

`loc = pm.response.headers.get("Location");`

Just in case, if the subsequent request(s) need the specific info, like header value, then you can also store/set it as environment variable as below, and reuse further

`pm.environment.set("redirURL", loc);`

```
var loc = null;
pm.test("Collect redirect location", function () {
   pm.response.to.have.header("Location");
   loc = pm.response.headers.get("Location");
   if (loc !== undefined) {
      pm.environment.set("redirURL", loc);
   }
});
```

**The advantage is - the value collected in the variable can be manipulated.**

But it all depends on the situation. Like, you might want to extract and pre/post-process the redirect URL.

For example,

While running the test collection, you would like to collect the value in a variable and change it to point to the mock server's ***host:port***.

Answer (score 1):

[HeadersList](http://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/HeaderList.html) has the method `has(item, valueopt) → {Boolean}`, so easiest way to check the header is:

```
const base_url = pm.variables.get("base_url")

pm.test("Redirect to OAuth2 endpoint", () => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.headers.has("Location",`${base_url}/oauth2/`)).is.true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
pm.test("Location value is correct", function () {
   pm.expect(pm.response.headers.get('Location')).to.eql('http://google.com');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Postman also supports ES6/ES2015 syntax as well, allowing us to use arrow functions.

So here's how a simple test to verify that the common response headers are present:

```
pm.test("Verify response headers are present ", () => {
    pm.response.to.have.header("Date");
    pm.response.to.have.header("Content-Length");
    pm.response.to.have.header("Content-Type");
});
```

Of course, you can check for any custom headers you may have returned by your API.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [BDD](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd) expect/should style:

```
pm.test("Redirect location is correct", () => {
   pm.expect(pm.response).to.include.header("Location");
   pm.expect(pm.response).to.have.header("Location", "http://example.com/expected-redirect-url");
});
```